# Possible regular expression backtracking problem in redash sql

Tags: regex, backtracking, redash

I have logged user's actions on the website like the following ones:

```
00:00 firstpage.textbox.hover
00:01 firstpage.textbox.push
00:02 firstpage.textbox.type
00:03 firstpage.textbox.submit
```

I am trying to find if there was a specific pattern of consequentive actions, e.g.

```
firstpage.textbox.type firstpage.textbox.submit
```

which may have any other actions before, between or after them.

What I have done so far is that I have concatenated actions to one string like:

```
firstpage.firstblock.open firstpage.textbox.push firstpage.textbox.type firstpage.textbox.submit
```

and then applied the following regular expression in order to find if there was a pattern I am interested in

```
select regexp_count(concatenated actions, '.*firstpage.textbox.type.*firstpage.textbox.submit.*') from t
```

Everyting is working fine, however I get the following error when trying to execute my query on data with more than about 50 items

> Error running query: The regular expression provided for REGEXP_COUNT produced excessive matches. Rewrite the expression. code:
>   8002 context: The complexity of matching the regular expression
>   exceeded predefined bounds. Try refactoring the regular expression to
>   make each choice made by the state machine unambiguous.

I think the problem is because of backtracking in my regular expression like `'A.*B.*C'`.

Do you know to change this regex in order to avoid this problem?

Comment: You might remove the first `.*` at least.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, it increased the lower bound of the data length, however there still comes the same error

Comment: I think, you can also remove the last '.*' and then make the mifddle no-greedy: 'firstpage.textbox.type.*?firstpage.textbox.submit'

Comment: The last `.*` does not play any role here, it may remain. The second `.*` can be turned to lazy, but then it will make the pattern slower if the `C` part is closer to the end of the string. This is not the solution. Unroll-the-loop is. But the regex engine must support a lookahead because the right-hand pattern is a multicharacter string. I doubt this one does.